# ttestbf: Error in is.infinite(c(x, y))

Tags: r

This is a question about an error in R's package BayesFactors.
When I tried the code generated in [this example](http://blog.efpsa.org/2014/11/17/bayesian-statistics-what-is-it-and-why-do-we-need-it-2/), I can use ttestBF fine.

However, when I tried running ttestBF on my data I got the following error:

Error in is.infinite(c(x, y)) : 
  default method not implemented for type 'list'

I also get that error if I create very simple data like this:

```
why <- data.frame(sensitivity = c(5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9), perspective = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
ttestBF(sensitivity ~ perspective, data = why)
t.test(sensitivity ~ perspective, data = why)
```

The t.test works fine. I imagine it is a very simple issue, but I can't figure this out, and I guess others might face similar issues.

Answer (score 3):

I eventually got the answer from the [relevant github Issues thread](https://github.com/richarddmorey/BayesFactor/issues/78).

```
BayesFactor::ttestBF(formula=sensitivity ~ perspective, data = why)
```